# error forecast autoplot: coerce is not an exported object from colorspace

Tags: r, plot, forecast

trying to plot a time series using autoplot.
reproducible example:

```
library(forecast)
 WWWusage %>% ets %>% forecast(h=20) -> fc
 autoplot(WWWusage, series="Data") + 
     autolayer(fc, series="Forecast") + 
     autolayer(fitted(fc), series="Fitted")

Error: 'coerce' is not an exported object from 'namespace:colorspace'
```

Comment: This works for me with a fresh install of packages. colorspace current version is 1.4.1 and `coerce` is exported. You should update packages.

Comment: updated all packages to no avail. Now colorspace is 1.4.1 and ggplot is 3.10

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your first fc instance with its data attribute: fc$x

BTW, this holds for other forecast library methods, eg, holt(), hw().

The following worked for me:

```
library(forecast)
WWWusage %>% ets %>% forecast(h=20) -> fc
autoplot(WWWusage, series="Data") + 
    autolayer(fc$x, series="Forecast") + 
    autolayer(fitted(fc), series="Fitted")
```

For documentation on forecast() output attributes, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.7/topics/forecast